# "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. [...]" when using neo4django.auth and neo4django.admin with only neo4j db

Tags: python, django, neo4j, neo4django

I am building an application in Django 1.4.5 with neo4django (github version). I am currently trying to enable the admin interface as instructed on https://neo4django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html

With the following settings when i hit /admin I get the error 
`settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.`

My **settings.py** includes the following

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}
NEO4J_DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':7474,
        'ENDPOINT':'/db/data'
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('neo4django.auth.backends.NodeModelBackend',)

SESSION_ENGINE = ('django.contrib.sessions.backends.file')

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'neo4django.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'neo4django.admin', 
    'neo4django.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin', 
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
    'users',
)
```

my **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from neo4django import admin


admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'my_app.views.MainHomePage', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

my **models.py**

```
from neo4django.db import models 
from neo4django.auth.models import User

class Person(models.NodeModel):
    email = models.EmailProperty(required = True, unique = True, indexed = True)

    # Neo4J RelationShips
    user = models.Relationship(User, rel_type = 'is_user')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.full_name.strip())
```

and my **admin.py** (as simple as it gets)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from neo4django.auth.models import User
from users.models import Person 

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

I have tried to either use a mysql together with neo4j, but I will either get the `no such table: django_site` error, where I have to first run syncdb, at least for the django_site table to be created or I just keep being redirected back to admin login page after successful log in.

Can someone point me to the right direction or at least tell me if using only neo4j is possible or not?

Comment: may be set any engine like this 
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
or else

Comment: `django.db.backends.dummy` raises `ImproperlyConfigured` error. Use a proper database backend instead - simplest being sqlite3

Comment: The `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',` was copied by the [mongoengine documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html). I have already tried with a mysql. So, I commented out the `django.contrib.sites` on `INSTALLED_APPS` and have changed to `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.'` and now I don't get the `ImproperlyConfigured` error or the `no such table: django_site` error. But I keep being redirected back to the admin login page. I have already tried to clean my browser cache. I guess my problem has more to do with the `neo4django` than `django`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the database settings, I typically just use

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```

I know it's annoying, but as long as you don't run syncdb, no sqlite file is created (and neo4django doesn't require syncdb anyway).

As far as the admin.py goes, I noticed you're importing from django- you need to be importing from neo4django. Try

```
from neo4django import admin
from users.models import Person

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...    

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

EDIT:

One more tip - you'll probably want to set `single=True` on the `user` relationship, since a  `Person` should only have one user. If a `User` should only have one person, I'd also set `related_single=True, related_name='person'` so you can access both as objects instead of managers.

Comment: Ok, I can live with the annoyance having to set a database even if you don't need it, until I or someone can find a solution ;-) Besides that I did the change to the admin.py and I still get redirected back to the admin login page on successful login.

Comment: Apparently the redirection to the admin login, had to do with the sessions. I changed my `SESSION_ENGINE` and now everything is ok. So the conclusion to my question is, 1. `from neo4django import admin` to the admin.py, 2. have a dummy mysqldb on `DATABASES` setting (until this is somehow resolved) and 3. try to use some other `SESSION_ENGINE` instead of the `django.contrib.sessionsbackends.file` (I recommend the [django-redis-sessions](https://github.com/martinrusev/django-redis-sessions)) to avoid the admin login redirection.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup

You have bad ENGINE for database.